I don't understand Green's derivation of the Laplace/Poisson equation inside an electrically charged body
I am currently reading George Green's "An Essay on the Application of Mathematical Analysis to the Theories of Electricity and Magnetism"Green's essay to gain some insight into the original idea of Green's functions. On page 14 of the digital transcript, he writes the following (for me very cryptic) few lines:
...we have therefore only to determine the value of $\delta V$ for the small sphere itself, which value is known to be $$\delta (2\pi a^2 \rho - 2/3 \pi b^2 \rho);$$
$\rho$ being equal to the density within the sphere and consequently to the
value of $\rho '$ at $p$.If now $x,$, $y,$, $z,$, be the co-ordinates of the centre of the sphere, we have
$$b^2 = (x,-x)^2+(y,-y)^2+(z,-z)^2,$$
and consequently
$$\delta (2\pi a^2 \rho - 2/3 \pi b^2\rho) = -4\pi\rho.$$
Hence, throughout the interior of the mass $$0 = \delta V + 4\pi\rho$$
of which, the equation $0=\delta V$ for any point exterior to the body is a particular case...
The $\delta$ here means the Laplace operator. I have so far understood all that preceeds this and most of what follows, but this computation makes no sense to me. I simply don't see how he arrived at the equation $$\delta (2\pi a^2 \rho - 2/3 \pi b^2 \rho).$$ The final result $0 = \delta V + 4\pi\rho$ is of course a classic one in the theory of electrostatics and can be arrived at in many ways. But what is the reasoning behind Green's derivation?

I calculate the potential at a point with position $\vec{r}  = b \hat{z}$ at distance $b$ from the center of a sphere with radius $a>b$, with the origin at the center of the sphere.
\begin{align}
V = \int \frac{\rho\, d^3r'}{|\vec{r}'-\vec{r}|}
\end{align}
I assume that since $a$ is small, we can treat the charge density as constant throughout the sphere. So
\begin{align}
V = \rho\int \frac{\, d^3r'}{|\vec{r}'-\vec{r}|} = \rho I
\end{align}
In spherical coordinates, we have
\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac{\, r'^2 \sin\theta' dr' d\theta' d\phi'}{\sqrt{r'^2 + b^2 - 2r'b\cos\theta'}}\\
&= 2\pi \int_0^{a} r'^2 dr' \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin\theta' d\theta'}{\sqrt{\alpha - \beta\cos\theta'}}
\end{align}
where $\alpha = r'^2 + b^2$ and $\beta = 2r' b$. Carrying out the $\theta'$ integral, we get
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{2\pi}{b}\int_0^{a}dr' r'\left(\sqrt{r'^2 + b^2 + 2 r' b} -\sqrt{r'^2 +b^2 - 2r'b}\right)\\
&= \frac{2\pi}{b} \left(\int_0^{a} dr' r' |r' + b| - \int_0^{a} dr' r'|r' -b|\right)\\
&= \frac{2\pi}{b}\left(I_1 - I_2\right)
\end{align}
The first integral on the RHS is
\begin{align}
I_1 = \frac{a^3}{3} + \frac{a^2b}{2}
\end{align}
The second is
\begin{align}
I_2 &= \int_0^b dr' r' (b - r') + \int_b^a dr' r' (r' - b)\\
&= \frac{b^3}{6} + \left(\frac{a^3}{3} - \frac{a^2b}{2} + \frac{b^3}{6}\right)
\end{align}
So we get
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{2\pi}{b}\left(a^2b - \frac{b^3}{3}\right)\\
&= 2\pi a^2 - \frac{2}{3}\pi b^2
\end{align}
and finally
\begin{align}
V = \rho I = 2\pi  a^2\rho - \frac{2}{3}\pi  b^2\rho
\end{align}
as claimed.
